How do I cross-reference a kable table in Quarto?
The code below only produces a cross reference that reads @out .

---
title: "Test"
format: pdf
editor: visual
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.

See @out

```{r}
#| label: out
#| tbl-cap: my caption
library(knitr)
kable(mtcars)


I think you want to wrap the whole example in a four tick code fence. This makes the example easier to read. I tried to include the additional tic on the containing fence lines, but there weren't enough characters for the edit to take. I think you can edit your own question to add those marks to make the question easier to read. Good luck with cross referencing.

Use the prefix tbl in both the cross reference (@tbl-out) and the code chunk label: tbl-out. When the label is outside of a code chunk, also the # character like #tbl-out.
See @tbl-out

```{r}
#| label: tbl-out
#| tbl-cap: my caption
library(knitr)
kable(mtcars)
```


Output:

For more see the documentation on quarto table cross-references.

Yes, that is helpful. I have that syntax in my code now and it will not resolve the cross-reference. It is endless, I just recompile and recompile, shut Rstudio down and it never resolves it. It's kind of ridiculous tbh.

Cross-references can be vexing. In my experience, cross-referencing problems are general caused by a mis-match between the label and the reference.
